# Table bigger than container with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

How can I make a table that is bigger than its parent container to have a **horizontal scroll**:

```html
<div style="background: pink; width: 200px">
  <table style="background: rgba(2,2,2, 0.2); width: 500px">
    <thead>
      <th>th</th>
      <th>th</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I need the table with a horizontal scroll.

Comment: There was nothing in the question which mentions or necessitates HTML5, CSS3 or SASS. Please don't throw every tag possible at questions.

Comment: I was add overflow-x: scroll; in first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `overflow: scroll;` on the parent element:

```css
.table-container {
  background: pink; 
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.table {
  background: rgba(2,2,2, 0.2); 
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>th</th>
      <th>th</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `overflow-x: auto` or `overflow-x: scroll` to the parent.

```html
<div style="background: pink; width: 200px; overflow-x: auto;">
  <table style="background: rgba(2,2,2, 0.2); width: 500px">
    <thead>
      <th>th</th>
      <th>th</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div style="background: pink; width: 200px; overflow: scroll">
  <table style="background: rgba(2,2,2, 0.2); width: 500px">
    <thead>
      <th>th</th>
      <th>th</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```